# Using Team Foundation Server, is it possible to connect to a remote MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, version-control, tfs

My website is built on WordPress, hosted on a remote server, and needs version control. Is it possible for me to use Team Foundation Server to connect to this remote MySQL database to use version control whenever I'm working on this WordPress site? If so, what are the basic steps? If not, what is the preferred method of using source control for WordPress sites?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with content management systems is that you are not looking to put WordPress under source but your instance of WordPress. Automatic already have WordPress under source.

My host WP-Engine provide a way to checkpoint or snapshot WordPress using GIT as the backing mechanism but it is not really putting it under source control. Source control is really best at source first, but CMS is about instance first.

You can use Vaultpress to backup your site or find a host that supports using GIT. WP Engine also provide a way to get and access your WordPress crossings in GIT.